# iPhone tapJoy and UIView

Tags: objective-c, sdk, cocos2d-iphone

Tapjoy has an SDK option to call a featured app with the line of code:

```
//Example
-(void)getFeaturedApp:(NSNotification*)notifyObj
{
[TapjoyConnect showFeaturedAppFullScreenAd]; 
}
```

However, I am trying to get the fullscreenAd to actually encompass 90% of the screen, not all of it. An investigation into the SDK reveals that these methods are tied to the UIViewController.

For example, the definition of

```
-(UIView*) showFeaturedAppFullScreenAd:(NSString*) adURL 
{
return [self showFeaturedAppFullScreenAd:adURL withFrame:self.view.bounds];
}
```

would it make sense to re-write the last bit 
withFrame: self.view.[bounds * 0.9f]];

EDIT: So, the goal is still to get this ad to not take up the whole screen. HOWEVER, the above method attempt did not work.

I tried:

```
{
return [self showFeaturedAppFullScreenAd: adURL withFrame:(self.view.bounds) * 0.9f];
}
```

and when compiling, it produced two build errors, both saying: Invalid operands to binary *

I am going to try out modifying the 'bounds' definition, but any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: so you're saying my method is bunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel this thread is no longer relevant to where I am now. I have discovered that it is not as simple as merely multiplying a float by a UIView property like bounds, or replacing it with another CGRect such as applicationFrame (which is also a property of UIView)

given that the metadata has likely been irreparably damaged, I'm closing this thread.